# how to call function assign in a variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I declare a function and assigned it to a Variable, inside the function was other functions. Normally, at first load of the page it loads the functions etc. When i used the variable in an ajax success callback, it says that the `init()` function is not a function.

This is my sample jquery function assigned to a variable called `GRID`:

```
    var Grid = (function() {
       function init( config ) { ... }
         .
         .
         .
       function addItems( $items ) { ... }
      return { init: init, . . . addItems: addItems }
    }
```

();

and i have a this ajax call

```
     function updateItems{
      .
      .
      .
      .
       jQuery.ajax({

            type: 'get',
            url:  ajaxURL,
            data: ajaxData,
            dataType: 'json',

            //Ajax call is successful
            success: function ( response ) {
                //Add new posts
               Grid.init();

            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });
        .
        .
        .
        }
```

What's wrong with the codes? why would the Inspector returns an error that says **Grid.init() is not a function**? please help

Comment: `Grid` is **not a function**, nor an object, the function looks like it's an IIFE, otherwise why does it start with a parentheses, that returns `undefined` unless you explicitly return something, and you can't call that function later on

Comment: is `var Grid` declared in the same scope (containing function, or global scope) as `updateItems`?

Comment: `var Grid` is declared as global scope and also `updateItems`.  @billy what's wrong with my code?

Comment: do you call your grid function whilst defining it... `var Grid = (function() { ... })();` <~~ note the calling braces

Comment: Yes. I have the () braces in my codes. I'll edit the question. I totally spaced out putting the question. I have it in my codes, at first load it is working, but when the ajax is called, it won't init the Grid again. @billy

Comment: `function updateItems{` <~~ seems invalid

Comment: Oh. the braces in the function. Wait i'll add it up in my codes. See if it works. @billy.

Comment: Addes () after the `updateItems` but it still says `Grid.init`is not a function.

Comment: Still not a function. @billy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var Grid = (function() {
   function init( config ) { ... }
     .
     .
     .
   function addItems( $items ) { ... }

   // explicitly return the functions, or properties you want to be attached to `Grid`
   return {
       init: init,
       .
       .
       .
       addItems: addItems
   }
// assuming you want this to be immediately invoked function expression
})();
```

Comment: Sorry, i forget to add the part for the return.

Comment: I have the return in my var grid, edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You defined init inside of the scope of the iife, but do not add it as a function of Grid.

you should do

`Grid.init = function(){}`

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
var Grid = {
   init  : function( config ) { ... }
     .
     .
     .
   addItems : function( $items ) { ... }
}
```

you should define init as a property inside Grid and the value of that property is the return of the function, hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your case there : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/raL1qqmh/)

The Grid :

```
var Grid = (function() {
  function init(config) {
    console.log('--- INIT')
  }
  
  function addItems($items) {
    console.log('--- ADD ITEMS')
  }
  
  return { init: init, addItems: addItems };
})();
```

Then the function with the Ajax Call :

```
function updateItems() {
  jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url:  ajaxURL,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
         Grid.init();
         Grid.addItems();
      }
  });
}
```

And I call this function :

```
updateItems();
```

Everything is fine for me. The console outputs :

> --- INIT
>
> --- ADD ITEMS

Can you spot a difference with your code ?

Are you sure `Grid` is global or in the same scope as `updateItems` ?